# Flutter Firestore Update Where

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a query that retrieves a single row given a where clause and updates it. I understand that Firebase doesn't support an `UpdateWhere` operations so I'm trying to use a `Transaction` instead.

I'm having difficulty making it work, maybe I'm too used to sql dbs... Here's my broken code

```
try {
    final whereQuery = _db
        .doc(userPath(user))
        .collection("someInnerCollection")
        .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
        .limit(1);

    await _db.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        final entry = await transaction.get(whereQuery);  // This doesn't compile as .get doesn't take in a query
        await transaction.update(entry, {
            "someValue": "newValue",
        });
    });
} catch (e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the test I’ve made, I would suggest the following to achieve what you mention:

Based on the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63025542/13171940):

> As you can see from the API documentation,  [where()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#where)  returns a  [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query)  object. It's not a DocumentReference.
>
> Even if you think that a query will only return one document, you still have to write code to deal with the fact that it could return zero or more documents in a  [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)  object. I suggest reviewing the  [documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query)  to see examples.

After doing the query consult, you have to get the `DocumentReference` for that given result.

Then, you can use that reference to update the field inside a [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)

```dart
try {
    final post = await firestore
        .collection('someInnerCollection')
        .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
            //Here we get the document reference and return to the post variable.
            return snapshot.docs[0].reference;
        });

    var batch = firestore.batch();
    //Updates the field value, using post as document reference
    batch.update(post, { 'someValue': 'newValue' }); 
    batch.commit();
    
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing! Nice

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `DocumentSnapshot` back in the `update()` operation instead of `DocumentReference` itself. Try refactoring the like this:

```
final docRefToUpdate = _db.collection("colName").doc("docId");

await _db.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  final entry = await transaction.get() // <-- DocRef of document to update in get() here
  await transaction.update(docRefToUpdate, {
    // Pass the DocumentReference here ^^
    "someValue": "newValue",
  });
});
```

Comment: You'll have to create that `docRefToUpdate` in the transaction itself by reading document ID from `entry.`

Comment: Yes, you're on the correct track but unfortunately `transaction.get()` doesn't take in a query but a doc reference instead. This is the issue itself, as I don't know how to execute the whereQuery within the transaction

Comment: @Martin true. If you are trying to update multiple documents then [Batched Writes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#batch-write) might be a viable option as well. You'll have to run the query, then loop over all the matched documents and add them in batch update and commit it.

Comment: From [FlutterFire's documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#:~:text=Transactions%20are%20useful),  _"Transactions are useful when you want to update a field based on its current value, or the value of another field. If you want to write multiple documents without using the documents current state, a batch write should be used."_

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last update. You're not passing anything in `transaction.get()`. I'm trying to update *only one entry/document*, I just want to make the where/update within a single transaction.

Comment: @Martin you should be passing DocumentReference of the document you are trying to update in there. But since you cannot run a query in txn, you'll have to run it beforehand and get reference to that document.

Comment: so `transaction.get()` is useless? I can't pass in the doc reference as I don't know the id - that's why I'm doing the whereQuery

Comment: @Martin at least this case yes since you would have to run query before transaction to get reference to that document at first place. Though a query followed by update operation without a Txn should do the job unless a transaction is required if you are handling any virtual currency like things.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a collection reference and then update single fields using .update().

```
final CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

await collectionReference.doc(user.uid).collection('yourNewCollection').doc('yourDocumentInsideNestedCollection').update({
        'singleField': 'whatever you want,
      });
```

Same code using "where"

```
collectionReference.doc(user.uid).collection('yourNewCollection').doc().where('singleField', isEqualTo: yourValue).update({
            'singleField': 'whatever you want,
          });
```

Comment: I need to execute a where statement beforehand. I'm updating particular entries within a nested collection.

Comment: See revised code above for nested collections

Comment: I don't know the `yourDocumentInsideNestedCollection` that's why I need to run the where clause... The question is whether I can run all of this inside a transaction, e.g. the where clause to get the id and the update

Comment: You can use where inside of the collection reference I believe let me see what I can find

Comment: Please check the revised code above