# Updating items in Firestore using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a friend req type Functionality
So if I tap on add friend button the name of Current Logged in person should be added to the request list of person named I searched.

[image: Firestore Structure]

So from my app when I click on add friend button, let say current logged in user is 'c@c.com' and I search for 'd@d.com' then 'c@c.com' user name should be added in the requests array of the person 'd@d.com'.

This is my search method to search a user

```
void onSearch() async {
    await _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: _search.text)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userMap = value.docs[0].data();
      });
    });
  }
```

What should I write in addUser method ?

```
void addUser() async {
    await _firestore
            .collection("users")
            .where("email", isEqualTo: _search.text)
            .get()
           ;
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write the new friend request to the database., but none of the code you shared writes to the database, so it's hard to say where the problem is in that code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my addUser() code is not complete I don't know how can I add items to array in firestore.

Comment: Adding items to and removing items from an array is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array. To learn how to update all documents that match a query, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007692/how-to-get-the-document-ref-to-a-where-clause-firestore/63025542#63025542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn how to add items to and remove items from an array, see the Firebase documentation on [updating an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array). To learn how to update all documents that match a query, see [How to get the document ref to a where clause firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007692/how-to-get-the-document-ref-to-a-where-clause-firestore/63025542#63025542)